# How can I seperate the input file according to the number of cases?

Tags: python, file

I have a programming problem in Python where I answer according to the input file. In this test file:

```
2
5
0.0
25.0
50.0
75.0
100.0
6
12.3
-67.1
122.8
428.4
-15.9
221.0
```

The first line, '2', represents the number of cases present in this file. We also have '5' and '6', which represents the number of floats in the cases. How can I split the file according to the number of cases?

Comment: Why have 5 and 6? Or even 2? If you control this data. Separate the floats by an empty line then it’d be simple to use `itertools.groupby` to get the floats and you’d have your 2, 5, and 6 programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the input is in a file named `input.txt`, you can read the floats separately using something like this

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
no_of_test_cases = int(f.readline().strip())
i = 0
while i < no_of_test_cases:
    no_of_floats = int(f.readline().strip())
    floats = []
    for _ in range(no_of_floats):
        floats.append(float(f.readline().strip()))
    print(floats)
    # Do your calculations/operations
    i += 1
```

Which gives

```
[0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0]
[12.3, -67.1, 122.8, 428.4, -15.9, 221.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment you don’t need the 2, 5, and 6 I’d suggest if you control the data just have the floats and use new lines to separate them but `itertools.groupby` can still be used here just determine if there is a period in the line and you have your floats.

```
from itertools import groupby 
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    all_floats = [list(map(float, g)) for  k, g in groupby(f, lambda s: '.' in s) if k]
    no_of_cases = len(all_floats)
    case_lens = list(map(len, all_cases))
```

Comment: Okok wow I wasn’t advanced enough to know about this, but now that I know, I could see how much simpler this is... This will come in handy for sure, thanks!